# Filter dates imported from a site

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to collect the date, hour and link of each of the games that have not yet started from this list:
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/uefa-champions-league/20192020/group-stage/r54142/

[image]

The problem is that the number of dates being imported is larger than the number of hours and links, because it is importing the dates of games that have already ended.

**Is there any way to filter the dates so that only the games that haven't started yet come?**

I leave below the formula I'm using and the link of my spreadsheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
              {
               IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span"),
               IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/span"),
               "https://"&IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href")
              }
             )
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-tfb7TTb-sEDIp0T8YfIIYwjBJLUgruckdgQN3oTEM8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified xpath:

For `IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span")`, how about the following modification?

From:

```
//td[@class='date no-repetition']/span
```

To:

```
//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
              {
               IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='date no-repetition' and ../td[@class='score-time status']]/span"),
               IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/span"),
               "https://"&IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='score-time status']/a/@href")
              }
             )
```

#### Result:

[image]

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, I believe it has now adjusted perfectly with the need! Thanks again mate!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.