# Repeat country name for each of the leagues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When using `IMPORTXML` to parse values, it creates a list with the name of the country and the name of the leagues, I would like for each of the leagues to specify the name of the country

Current formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("XXXXXXXXXX",
           "//country/title/text() | //country/leagues/title/text()")
```

Import result:

```
Argentina
Liga Profesional Argentina
Austria
2. Liga
Bundesliga
Belarus
Premier League
Belgium
First Division B
First Division A
```

After divide in two columns (I will use one another formula to divide into two columns):

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1,{1;IMPORTXML("XXXXXXXXXX","//country/title/text() | //country/leagues/title/text()")},(ROW(A1:A)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(sort(ROW($A$1:$A$2)+0,1,0)))))
```

```
COUNTRIES           LEAGUES

Argentina           Liga Profesional Argentina
Austria             2. Liga
Bundesliga          Belarus
Premier League      Belgium
First Division B    First Division A
```

Formula I tried to create:

```
=IMPORTXML("XXXXXXXXXX",
           "//country/title/text() and ..//country/leagues/title/text() | //country/leagues/title/text()")
```

Expected Import Result:

```
Argentina
Liga Profesional Argentina
Austria
2. Liga
Austria
Bundesliga
Belarus
Premier League
Belgium
First Division B
Belgium
First Division A
```

Final Expected Goal (I will use one another formula to divide into two columns):

```
COUNTRIES     LEAGUES

Argentina     Liga Profesional Argentina
Austria       2. Liga
Austria       Bundesliga
Belarus       Premier League
Belgium       First Division B
Belgium       First Division A
```

**In summary I need a way to duplicate country names when there is more than one league per country.**

Comment: For example, `<title>Austria</title>` can be seen only one time in the XML data. But in your expected result, there are 2 `Austria`. I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hello mate, I updated the question with the expected final result. @Tanaike

Comment: When I want to repeat a value that has no repetition, I use it for example: ```//div[@class='test' and..//div[@confirmed]]``` But as there is no specific class, it didn't work this model.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Can I ask you about the difference between `Expected Result:` and `Final Expected Goal`? In your current situation, you have already been able to obtain `Expected Result:`?

Comment: Here in this question you managed to explain how to do it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061261/11462274 - There is no difference between the expected result and the final expected result, I just wanted to show you why I need the name of the country to repeat, so when there are two columns the country exists in column A and the leagues in column B. The problem is that currently there is no repetition of the country name for each league, I would like to know if there is any option

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. In your question, at first, you want to achieve `Expected Result:` and, as next step, you want to achieve `Final Expected Goa`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly my friend. Dividing the data into two columns I can do, my problem is to find a way to repeat the names of the ```countries``` when collecting the data. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Dividing the data into two columns I can do`, can you provide your formula retrieving `Expected Import Result:`?

Comment: I added the formula in ```After divide in two columns (I will use one another formula to divide into two columns)``` included to the question. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. When I tested your formula, it seems that the titles of "COUNTRIES" include the titles of "LEAGUES". For example, "Bundesliga" is included in "COUNTRIES". And "Belgium" is included in "LEAGUES". I think that this is different from your expected result. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve `Final Expected Goal` at the bottom of your question.
- In your formula, it seems that the titles of "COUNTRIES" include the titles of "LEAGUES". For example, "Bundesliga" is included in "COUNTRIES". And "Belgium" is included in "LEAGUES". I thought that this might be different from your expected result.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the built-in functions in Spreadsheet is used.

- The values of "COUNTRIES" can be retrieved with the xpath of `//country/title`.
- The values of "LEAGUES" can be retrieved with the xpath of `//leagues/title`.

  - In your case, there are several values of "LEAGUES" in a "COUNTRIES".
- In order to retrieve "COUNTRIES" for each "LEAGUES", I used `//leagues[position()>1]/id | //country/title` and I referred the sample formula from [this site](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/fill-blank-cells-with-the-values-above/).

From above xpath and formula, I would like to propose the following sample formula.

#### Sample formula:

```
={
ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(ROW(A2:A64),ROW(A2:A64)/IF(IMPORTXML(A1,"//leagues[position()>1]/id | //country/title")<>0,TRUE,FALSE),
IMPORTXML(A1,"//leagues[position()>1]/id | //country/title"))),IMPORTXML(A1,"//leagues/title")
}
```

- In this formula, the URL of `http://lineuptoday.com/api/matches/bydate?date=01&month=11&year=2020` is put in a cell "A1".
- As an important point, in this case, it is required to set the last row number (in your case, it's `64`.) When the last row number is not set, the formula becomes a bit complecate and the process cost becomes very high. So in this answer, as another method, I would like to also propose a custom formula created with Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost might be a bit reduction.

#### Result:

[image]

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the custom function created with Google Apps Script is used.

#### Sample script:

Please put `=SAMPLE("http://lineuptoday.com/api/matches/bydate?date=01&month=11&year=2020")` to a cell.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const root = XmlService.parse(res.getContentText()).getRootElement();
  const n = root.getNamespace();
  return root.getChildren().reduce((ar, c) => {
    const titleCountry = c.getChild("title", n).getText();
    c.getChildren("leagues", n).forEach(l => {
      ar.push([titleCountry, l.getChild("title", n).getText()])
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
}
```

- In this case, the output result is the same with above sample formula. But it is not required to set the last row number.

### Note:

- These sample formula and script are for the URL of `http://lineuptoday.com/api/matches/bydate?date=01&month=11&year=2020`. When other URL is used, the result you expected might not be retrieved. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 2):

Not much to add to @Tanaike's excellent answer, but I guess you could filter instead of fixing the range:

```
=ArrayFormula({vlookup(
        filter(row(A:A),A:A<>"",isna(vlookup(A:A,C:C,1,0))),
        {if(ISTEXT(vlookup(A:A,C:C,1,0)),row(A:A)),A:A},2),
     filter(A:A,A:A<>"",isna(vlookup(A:A,C:C,1,0)))})
```

assuming that you have

```
=IMPORTXML("http://lineuptoday.com/api/matches/bydate?date=01&month=11&year=2020","//country/title/text() | //country/leagues/title/text()")
```

in column A and

```
=IMPORTXML("http://lineuptoday.com/api/matches/bydate?date=01&month=11&year=2020","//country/title/text()")
```

in column C.

[image]

Flatten may be used to put both columns into a single column if required.

BTW what is England Premier League two division 2? Haven't heard of that one.

Comment: Good evening Tom, thank you for complementing in options! Removing your doubt, this second division of the Premier League is linked to tournaments for players under 23 years old. Haha. Link to competition: https://www.premierleague.com/premier-league-2-explained